# Aapt2 throws error that was present in previous build

Tags: android, react-native

I have changed my package name and accidentally added  a comma in name, that was fixed in later build, but I'm still facing this error

> Output:  D:\react projects\MyBestNaturalHealth\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:2: error: attribute 'package' in  tag is not a valid Android package name: 'com.blitzapp.mybestnaturalhealth;'.

the ";" symbol was removed in later builds but still facing this issue.

What I have done is tried gradlew clean command but its not working

Comment: What are you using to build? If you're using gradle, you can go to the main project directory and run "gradlew clean app:assembleDebug" to do a clean build. If it's the cache that's the problem, you can delete the whole gradle cache directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already solved this issue, I forgot to change the bundle in build.gradlew file